# How to use jquery.rating.js in a list view?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam using jquery.rating.js for rating functionality in my web app. When iam using this rating tool in a list view the rating value is not getting the correct value. Each time when i click on the rating it will add to the previous rating.

```js
< link rel = stylesheet type = "text/css"
href = "jquery.rating.css" >
  < script src = "jquery.form.js" > < /script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script >
  < script src = "jquery.MetaData.js" > < /script>
<script src="jquery.rating.js"></script >
  < script src = "jquery.rating.pack.js" > < /script>


<script language="javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
  
 $(".auto-submit-star").rating({ callback: function(value, url){
  var rating = $('.star-rating-control .star-rating-on').length;
  var name = this.name;
  
  var pid = name.substring(0, name.length - 1);
  var username = document.getElementById("username").innerHTML;
  var prating = document.getElementById("pRating").innerHTML;
  
  document.getElementById("pRating").innerHTML = rating;
  
  alert(rating);
  alert(prating);
  
  rating = Math.abs(rating - prating);
  
  
  $.get("/StrutsBlog / rating.do ? rating = "+rating+" & pid = "+pid+" & username = "+username, function(data, status){
       
     });
 
 } });
});

</script>
```

```html
</TR>
<% int j=0; java.util.List<PostBean>pbeanList = (java.util.List
  <PostBean>) request .getAttribute("postlist"); System.out.println("postlist" + pbeanList); for (PostBean pbean : pbeanList) { %>


    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#f0e6d5" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>


    <TR bgcolor="#f0e6d5">
      <TD width="18%" valign="top">
        &nbsp;
        <FONT SIZE="2" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#000000"><B>
 <%=pbean.getPostby()%>
</B></font>
        <BR>Member #
        </FONT>
      </TD>
      <TD>
        <img src="http://saloon.javaranch.com/ubb/posticon.gif" border="0">
        <FONT SIZE="1" color="#800080" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#000000">
 posted 
</FONT>
        <HR size="1" color="#dedfdf">
        <FONT SIZE="2" FACE="Verdana, Arial" color="#000000">
 <%=pbean.getPostdesc()%>
</FONT>
        <a><img  src="fetchpostimage.do?postid=<%=pbean.getPostid()%>" width="50" height="50"/></a>
        <HR size="1" color="#dedfdf">
        <FONT SIZE="1" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#000000">
 Postedon:<%=pbean.getPostedon()%> 
 &nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="deletepost.do?tid=<%=request.getParameter("tid")%>&pid=<%=pbean.getPostid()%>"><img title="Remove" alt="Remove" src="images/thrash.png"/></a>
 <a href="editPost.jsp?tid=<%=request.getParameter("tid")%>&pid=<%=pbean.getPostid()%>&description= <%=pbean.getPostdesc()%>"><img title="Edit" alt="Edit" src="images/edit-icon.png"/></a>
 <input name="<%=pbean.getPostid()%><%=j %>" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star"/> 
 <input name="<%=pbean.getPostid()%><%=j %>" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star"/> 
 <input name="<%=pbean.getPostid()%><%=j %>" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star" checked="checked"/>
 <input name="<%=pbean.getPostid()%><%=j %>" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star"/> 
 <input name="<%=pbean.getPostid()%><%=j %>" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star"/>
</FONT>


      </td>
    </tr>

    <%j++;} %>
```

Please help me on this..